# Match width of largest widget in Column in QGridLayout

Tags: qt, qgridlayout

I have a simple QGridLayout of different QGroupBox widgets. These QGroupBox Widgets could have variable wides (depending on how much content goes in each one.

When stacking the groupboxes into a grid, the next column starts at the right of the longest groupbox, but if there are shorter groupboxes in the same column, there will be empty space.

Is there an approach to basically force every single widget in a column to be the width of the maximum width widget?

Basically I want a column to go from this:

```
<===== Widget 1 Width =======>

<== Widget 2 Width ==> (empty)

<=Widget 1 Width=> (empty    )
```

To this:

```
<===== Widget 1 Width =======>

<===== Widget 2 Width =======>

<===== Widget 3 Width =======>
```

Instead of leaving empty space before the next column, force the groupbox (or whatever widget is in the grid) to fill to the end. Right now the column just ends at whatever the largest width is, I still want that to happen, but I want the smaller widgets to fill to that size as well

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

did you try to change the size policy of widgets in the layout to expanding?

according to the document :

> QSizePolicy::Expanding : The sizeHint() is a sensible size, but the widget can be shrunk and still be useful. The widget can make use of extra space, so it should get as much space as possible (e.g. the horizontal direction of a horizontal slider).